# Mathematical Olympiad Treasures Problem 3.27 how many ways to fill a table such that product of entries equal -1

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The question is:

In how many ways can one fill a $m × n$ table with $±1$ such that the product of the entries in each row and each column equals $−1$?

So far I believe that $m,n$ must have equal parity, but have not made much progress past that.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much more progress necessary.

Hint: fill the top-left $(m-1)\times(n-1)$ subtable arbitrarily. Clearly there's one way to complete each of those $m-1$ rows, and one way to complete each of the $n-1$ columns. Then the question is: what condition is required for the completion of the final row to equal the completion of the final column?